# What is the max latency a LAN network can have if the maximum lenght is 100 meters (328 feet)?

Tags: networking, lan

Besides the question. What is the ideal latency a LAN network should have? And what is a good and bad latency?

Comment: It really depends on precisely what you mean by "latency".

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by LAN. And the cabling, and and...

Comment: @brianlmerritt the cabling is UTP-6 and by LAN i just mean a regular LAN network from one to computer to another having 328 feet between all devices.

Comment: There is no such thing as a max latency. There is a minimum latency which is always > 0ms but that stat can go up to infinity (even on a LAN). This is what happens every time a packet is blocked by a firewall for example. The firewall doesn't tell the requesting machine anything; that machine simply times out. A timeout can set an artificial max latency for a particular machine or application but that is something you configure and not a physical property of the network.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not well posed. The cable length itself does not cause geometric latency, because information over fiber optics travels at essentially the speed of light, which leads to a very modest 0.3micro secs.

The problem with cable length is `signal attenuation`, which becomes significant over such distances. Pure silica has basically very little attenuation (something of order 0.3 dB/km, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber-optic_communication#Attenuation)), but the impurities in the composition make all the difference because they can cause an attenuation of 1000 dB/km. Since this depends in detail on the fiber composition, it is impossible to say for sure which results **your** cable will achieve.

This attenuation causes, *indirectly* an increase in latency: in the presence of strong attenuation there will be significant packet loss, which, in the TCP protocol, means packets will have to be resent. The interval over which the sender waits for an acknowledgement from the receiver is dynamically adjusted to include the effects of latency and packet loss due to attenuation, so that the `window` (*i.e.* the time the sender waits before re-sending the packet if no acknowledgement is received) is increased accordingly. Thus signal attenuation causes packet loss, which causes increase in the window, which causes a decrease in throughput, and thus the *appearance* of latency.

[A simple experiment](http://www.ihiji.com/latent-latency/) shows that a 100Mb/s line in the presence of **no** latency but with **2%** packet loss is curtailed to an effective 3.7Mb/s, while the same, in the presence of a 30msec latency but no packet loss is curtailed to *only* 16.2Mbs.  You can see that the combination of high latency and strong signal attenuation is deadly for even the largest-throughput, commercially-available connections.

Most of the throughput decrease **not** due to signal attenuation is due latency inside routers; for this reason it is easy to find milli-sec ping travel times inside typical SOHO installations, which is actually quite good. A good rule of thumb is that anything below 30msec is excellent, while anything above is abnormal in typical SOHOs. Signal attenuation is counteracted by the introduction of signal amplifiers; latency *per se* instead requires providing direct routes between different components, the minimization of wifi sections, the monitoring of performance for APs and routers encountered along the way.